# @ApiModelProperty to swagger HTML report

Tags: java, html, swagger

I am creating microservice with java class using @ApiModelProperty annotation for swagger documentation.

Is it possible to generate HTML swagger documentation from this file using some IntelliJ plugin without deploying my microservice?